# Custom column names for statistics in tables with modelsummary and alignment

Tags: r, modelsummary

Following the example below, I want to write custom names of the column headers for the statistics and estimates: "Estimate", "95% CI", and "p value". Ideally, I would like to obtain a table where each of these three elements have their own column, so it is easier to align each of them. Is this possible with {modelsummary}? I want a table optimized for latex and html.

```r
library(modelsummary)
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)
m2 <- lm(wt ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)

msummary(list("M1" = m1, "M2" = m2),
         shape = term ~ model + statistic,
         statistic = "{p.value}",
         estimate = "{estimate} [{conf.low}; {conf.high}]")
```

|  | M1 / Est. | M1 / p | M2 / Est. | M2 / p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 34.661 [29.452; 39.870] | <0.001 | 1.773 [0.983; 2.563] | <0.001 |
| cyl | -1.587 [-3.043; -0.131] | 0.034 | -0.054 [-0.275; 0.166] | 0.618 |
| disp | -0.021 [-0.042; 0.000] | 0.054 | 0.008 [0.005; 0.011] | <0.001 |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |  | 32 |  |
| R2 | 0.760 |  | 0.790 |  |
| R2 Adj. | 0.743 |  | 0.776 |  |
| AIC | 167.1 |  | 46.4 |  |
| BIC | 173.0 |  | 52.3 |  |
| Log.Lik. | -79.573 |  | -19.205 |  |
| F | 45.808 |  | 54.661 |  |
| RMSE | 2.91 |  | 0.44 |  |

The expected table would look like this:

|  | M1 / Estimate | M1 / 95% CI | M1 / *p* value | M2 / Estimate | M2 / 95% CI | M2 / *p* value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 34.661 | [29.452; 39.870] | <0.001 | 1.773 | [0.983; 2.563] | <0.001 |
| cyl | -1.587 | [-3.043; -0.131] | 0.034 | -0.054 | [-0.275; 0.166] | 0.618 |

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the statistics individually in a vector in the `statistic` argument and then use `shape` to place them in columns:

```r
library(modelsummary)
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)
m2 <- lm(wt ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)
mod <- list("M1" = m1, "M2" = m2)

msummary(mod,
  escape = TRUE,
  shape = term ~ model + statistic,
  estimate = "estimate",
  statistic = c("p.value", "conf.low", "conf.high"))
```

[image]

[image]

Warning: In LaTeX, the confidence interval headers do not appear to be properly escaped, and the raw % signs break compilation of the documents. I had to go in and add a backslash in front: `\%`

Edit: In version 2.0.0 of `modelsummary`, the % signs are properly escaped by default.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, @Vincent. I'm just missing how to customize the names of the columns. Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible currently. Of course, this is extremely easy to edit manually after saving the table, so probably not a big deal in most applications. But I do think it would be a nice convenience feature to have, so I'll leave the Github issue open and look into it when I have time (which may not be for a little while, unfortunately).